# Event triggers by itself

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have no idea why function wich should run only when button is pressed runs by herself.

Here is my button declaration:

```
var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
    id: "buttonId",
    text: "Yes",
    press: this.fnB()
});
```

My controller looks like follows:

```
sap.ui.controller("<controller-name>", {

    fnA: function(){<button_declaration_here>},

    fnB: function(){console.log("Hello from fnB!");}

});
```

When I run the app I get:

> Hello from fnB!
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

No buttons pressed yet, so why do I get the hello message?

I use SAP WEB IDE if it matters...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
press: this.fnB()
```

**calls** `this.fnB()` and uses its return value to initialize the `press` property, exactly the way `x = foo()` **calls** `foo` and assigns its return value to `x`.

You probably wanted

```
press: this.fnB
```

or

```
press: this.fnB.bind(this)
```

so that you were assigning a reference to the function to `press`, not calling it and using its return value.

That second example probably needs some explaining: If we used just

```
press: this.fnB
```

that would assign the function to `press`, but when it was run, the `this` during the call to `fnB` wouldn't be the same as the `this` in the code above, because in JavaScript, the value of `this` within a function is usually determined by how the function was called.

Using `Function#bind`:

```
press: this.fnB.bind(this)
```

...creates a *new* function that, when called, will call the original function with the `this` value we give to `bind`.

Comment: I wanted `press: this.fnB`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a function from the controller in SAPUI5 you should use:

```
press: [this.fnB, oController]
```

After this declaration `this` refers to the controller not the event

Comment: In my particular case `this` refers to the controller, so there is no problem here. But your comment is still helpful.

Comment: I see then thats not needed ;)